# Why does `print.function` disagree with function bodies that are created with `substitute()`?

Tags: r

In R, it is possible to do a 'macro substitution' before executing a piece of code. Using this technique, one can dynamically embed a constant into a function body before actually creating the funciton, avoiding a variable look-up:

```
expr = substitute(function () s, list('s'='ABCDE'))
f    = eval(expr)
f()
# [1] "ABCDE"
environment(f)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Here, the enclosing environment is `R_GlobalEnv`, which does not contain the variable `s` at all, but the function can still return `"ABCDE"` correctly. This seems to mean that the returned string `"ABCDE"` was indeed not from a variable lookup, but is embedded into the function body.

But now if you print the function, you can see that `s` is still there, although it is not in `expr`:

```
print(f)
# function () s
print(expr)
# function() "ABCDE"
```

What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print.function` prints the `srcref` attribute rather than the actual source but

1. the `useSource=` argument can be used to specify that the actual function source be used.  It defaults to TRUE but can be specified as FALSE.
2. `body(f)` will show the actual body.
3. The srcref attribute can be removed using `attr(f, "srcref") <- NULL` in which case print will show the actual source.  It is also possible to overwrite the srcref attribute. `attr(f, "srcref") <- format(f)` which works because `format` uses the actual source.

Here is a demonstration.

```
expr <- substitute(function () s, list('s'='ABCDE'))
f <- eval(expr)

f
## function () s

print(f)
## function () s

print(f, useSource = FALSE)
## function () 
## "ABCDE"

attr(f, "srcref")
## function () s

body(f)
## [1] "ABCDE"

format(f)
## [1] "function () " "\"ABCDE\""    

f <- eval(expr)
attr(f, "srcref") <- NULL
f
## function () 
## "ABCDE"

f <- eval(expr)
attr(f, "srcref") <- format(f)
f
## function () 
## "ABCDE"
```